# Having a background color stop right after text ends

Tags: html, css

I have a div called `title-inverse` that I put a different background color behind than the container it sets in. The container is black and `title-inverse` has a white background color. I am wanting the white background color to stop right after the title ends.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Where the blue is in this image is where I want the black to be.

[image]

```css
.section-wrap {
 height: 80vh;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.section-block {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.sec-text {
 width: 30%;
 background: #000;
}
.section-content-left, .section-content-right {
 width: 70%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.title-inverse {
 background: #FFF;
 color: #000;
 padding: 5px 10px 2px 15px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 margin-top: 15%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.section-title:after {
 margin-top: 3px;
 height: 2px;
 width: 70px;
 background: #C3C3C3;
 display: block;
}
.section-description, #about-list li {
 color: #777;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: .5rem;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap">
    <div class="section-block right sec-img">
        <div id="img2" class="back" title=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-block sec-text left">
        <h2 class="title-inverse">ALUMINUM EXTRUDED PROFILE</h2>
        <div class="section-content-right" id="right-sec2">
            
            <p class="section-description">
                Our team has worked with both small start-ups to established corporations with the task of enhancing their online presence by refining 
                their brand to reach optimum user communication. Our ultimate goal is to improve brand awareness, while making connections with the clients' user-base. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works as long as the window is wide enough and the text doesn't wrap. What are you wanting when the window resizes? Should there always be a set amount of black to the right of the `.title-inverse`?

Comment: I want the text to wrap.

Comment: Always? You could change the header to: `<h2 class="title-inverse"> ALUMINUM EXTRUDED<br>PROFILE</h2>`

Comment: @TrevorNestman This did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option that might be close to what you want is [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break), but it is an experimental feature, so support is not great (especially IE and Edge): https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.section-wrap {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.section-block {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sec-text {
  width: 30%;
  background: #000;
}

.section-content-left,
.section-content-right {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title-inverse {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.title-text {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px 2px 15px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.section-description {
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: .5rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap">

  <div class="section-block right sec-img">
    <div id="img2" class="back" title=""></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section-block sec-text left">
    <h2 class="title-inverse"><span class="title-text">ALUMINUM EXTRUDED PROFILE</span></h2>
    
    <div class="section-content-right" id="right-sec2">
      <p class="section-description">
        Our team has worked with both small start-ups to established corporations with the task of enhancing their online presence by refining their brand to... 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Basically, I changed the title to:

```
<h2 class="title-inverse"><span class="title-text">ALUMINUM EXTRUDED PROFILE</span></h2>
```

And its CSS rules to:

```
.title-inverse {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

.title-text {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px 2px 15px;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```